# Grouping rows if their dates overlap, and ranking them

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

My situation is I have a table of transactions, with start and end dates. The problem is that often times these transaction dates overlap with each other, and I want to group these scenarios together.

For example in the case below, transaction #1 is the **"root"** transaction, while #2-#4 are overlapping with #1 and/or with each other. However, transaction #5 is not overlapping with anything, hence it is a new "root" transaction.

```
+----------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------------------+
| Transaction ID | StartDate |  EndDate  |                                  |
+----------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------------------+
|              1 | 1/1/2017  | 1/3/2017  | root transaction                 |
|              2 | 1/2/2017  | 1/6/2017  | overlaps with #1                 |
|              3 | 1/5/2017  | 1/10/2017 | overlaps with #2                 |
|              4 | 1/3/2017  | 1/13/2017 | overlaps with #2 and #3          |
|              5 | 1/15/2017 | 1/20/2017 | no overlap, new root transaction |
+----------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------------------+
```

Below is how I want the output to look. I want to

1. Identify the root transaction (column 4)
2. Rank the transactions in a chain by EndDate, so that the root is always = 1

---

```
+----------------+-----------+-----------+------------------+------+
| Transaction ID |   Start   |    End    | Root Transaction | Rank |
+----------------+-----------+-----------+------------------+------+
|              1 | 1/1/2017  | 1/3/2017  |                1 |    1 |
|              2 | 1/2/2017  | 1/6/2017  |                1 |    2 |
|              3 | 1/5/2017  | 1/10/2017 |                1 |    3 |
|              4 | 1/3/2017  | 1/13/2017 |                1 |    4 |
|              5 | 1/15/2017 | 1/20/2017 |                5 |    1 |
+----------------+-----------+-----------+------------------+------+
```

How would I go about this in SQL?

Comment: Please tag your question with the version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one method using an `OUTER APPLY`

```
Declare @YourTable table ([Transaction ID] int,StartDate date,EndDate date)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'1/1/2017','1/3/2017'),
(2,'1/2/2017','1/6/2017'),
(3,'1/5/2017','1/10/2017'),
(4,'1/3/2017','1/13/2017'),
(5,'1/15/2017','1/20/2017')

Select [Transaction ID]
      ,[Start] = StartDate
      ,[End]   = EndDate
      ,[Root Transaction]=Grp
      ,[Rank]  = Row_Number() over (Partition By Grp Order by [Transaction ID])
 From (
        Select A.*
              ,Grp = max(Flag*[Transaction ID]) over (Order By [Transaction ID])
         From (
                Select A.*,Flag = IsNull(B.Flg,1)
                 From @YourTable A
                 Outer Apply (
                              Select Top 1 Flg=0 
                               From  @YourTable 
                               Where (StartDate between A.StartDate and A.EndDate 
                                  or EndDate   between A.StartDate and A.EndDate )
                                 and [Transaction ID]<A.[Transaction ID]
                              ) B
              ) A
      ) A
```

Returns

[image]

> **EDIT - Some Commentary**

In the `OUTER APPLY`, Flag will be set to 1 or 0.  1 Indicates a New Group.  0 Indicates that the record will overlap with an existing range

Then the next query "up", We use the window function to apply a Grp Code (Flag*Trans ID).  Remember a new group is 1 and existing is 0.
 Now the window function will take max of this product, as it traverses the Transactions.

The final query is just to apply the Rank using the window function partition by the Grp, Order by Trans ID

If it helps with the visualization:

The 1st sub-query (outer apply) genererates

[image]

The 2nd sub-query generates

[image]

Comment: This is freaking amazing! It works, but I wasn't aware of OUTER APPLY, so lots of what you're doing is very new to me. If you have time could you break down what does Flg=0, how the outer apply is working, just explain it? I'm trying to understand it myself as well.

Comment: @RedVII Sure, I'll add some commentary in a few

Comment: Thanks! Very clever solution

Comment: FYI. this does not work if some rows belong to more than one branch. We need to use recursive CTE in that case.
Try to add (6,'1/1/2017','1/3/2017'),
(7,'1/1/2016','1/20/2017'),
(8,'1/1/2017','1/3/2017'),
(9,'1/15/2016','1/20/2017') and see if it still suit your need.

Comment: @thReality Yes, but that really wasn't the question was it?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti No offense, I just give more information for anyone who happens to see this query but has a slightly different condition on their data or expected result

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of "gaps-and-islands".  For your data, you can determine the "island"s by determining where each starts -- that is, where a record does not overlap with the previous record.  You can then get the rank using `row_number()`.

So, here is a method:

```
select t.*,
       min(transactionId) over (partition by island) as start,
       row_number() over (partition by island order by endDate) as rnk
from (select t.*,
             sum(startIslandFlag) over (order by startDate) as island
      from (select t.*,
                   (case when not exists (select 1
                                          from t t2
                                          where t2.startdate < t.startdate and
                                                t2.enddate >= t.startdate
                                         )
                         then 1 else 0
                    end) as startIslandFlag
            from t
           ) t
      ) t;
```

Notes:

- In the event that the lowest transaction id is not the "root", then a tweak may be needed to the code to get the transaction id with the minimum start date.
- If there are duplicate start dates in the code, a tweak may be needed with the cumulative sums (using an explicit `range` window).

Comment: I'm a little confused with the answer, since I don't have your dataset, and the t aliases are really throwing me off. Could this be made more relevant for my dataset, or simply guide me through what the code is doing in each subquery?

Comment: rather tan attempt to edit this answer, or add another that repeats this, please refer to this URL http://rextester.com/UTDR6041 where each part of this solution is run independently

Answer (score 1):

Identify the root transactions:

```
with roots as (
    select *
    from tran as t1
    where not exists (
        select 1
        from tran as t2
        where t2.Transaction_ID < t1.Transaction_ID
        and (
            t1.StartDate between t2.StartDate and t2.EndDate
            or
            t1.EndDate between t2.StartDate and t2.EndDate
            )
        )
    )
```

Create a two root system to capture all the overlaps in between them

```
select t.Transaction_ID,
    t.StartDate as [Start],
    t.EndDate as [End],
    r1.Transaction_ID as Root_Transaction,
    row_number() over (partition by r1.Transaction_ID order by t.EndDate) as [Rank]
from roots as r1
inner join roots as r2
on r2.Transaction_ID > r1.Transaction_ID
inner join tran as t
on t.Transaction_ID >= r1.Transaction_ID
and t.Transaction_ID < r2.Transaction_ID 
where not exists ( --this "not exists" makes sure r1 and r2 are consequetive roots
    select 1
    from roots as r3
    where r3.Transaction_ID > r1.Transaction_ID
    and r3.Transaction_ID < r2.Transaction_ID
    )
```